# Jface / swt Label that can scroll

Tags: swt, jface

First of all thanks for all the previous advice.

I have come across a rather tricky little problem.

I have a string which I want to display into a Label, normally no problem, but the string is longer than the label will allow. However the similar problem with the text box was resolved with the use of the swt awt hybrid. What I would like to do is replicate this with the label.

Is there way around this? or would the workaround be to have the text area to settext to desired text and then to set the text enable to false so it is grey text.

Could anybody advise?

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround to use Text is perfectly fine. You can mimic label behavior by setting appropriate background color and font and disable it. Also such "labels" are able to provide copy functionality, which is not possible for usual Labels.

Another workaround would be to calculate bounds of your String by using FontMetrics and then cut the string in the end with "..." and providing a tooltip with a full Sting length.

It is also possible to use `SWT.WRAP` constant for labels, thou it will be still restricted by the width of the Label.